# How do I create a custom search and filter?

Tags: 8, search

I have created a custom module to render forms on the front end (modules\custom_mod\src\Form\Contact\ContactUserForm.php) and stored the form values to a custom table.

I have also created a listing (admin end) of the stored data from table which I acheived with the help of controller (modules\custom_mod\src\Controller\Contact\ContactController.php).

In that listing, I have the *Edit* and *Delete* actions based on the ID from the table.

The file structure is below.

```
modules/custom_mod/
├── js
├── css
├── custom_mod.routing.yml
├── custom_mod.info.yml
├── custom_mod.module
├── custom_mod.libraries.yml
└── src
    ├── Form
        └── Contact
            └── ContactUserForm.php
            └── ContactUserStorage.php
            └── ContactAdminForm.php
            └── ContactAdminEdit.php
    ├── Controller
        └── Contact
            └── ContactController.php
```

Now I need a search box, a *From date* and *To date* filter, with an *Export (CSV)* button above the listing, so that the administrator user can filter or search accordingly.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a very easy month/year filter select box. For that I created a new form class which extends the FormBase class of Drupal 8.

To add filter and search inputs I added following values to the returning array:

```
namespace Drupal\my_sandbox\Controllers;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class TestController extends ControllerBase
{

public function test()
{

    $form = [];

    //add you custom code here...

    $form['form'] = [
        '#type'  => 'form',
    ];

    $form['form']['filters'] = [
        '#type'  => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $this->t('Filter'),
        '#open'  => true,
    ];

    $form['form']['filters']['text'] = [
        '#title'         => 'text',
        '#type'          => 'search'
    ];

    $form['form']['filters']['year'] = [
        '#title'         => 'Year',
        '#type'          => 'select',
        '#empty_value'   => 'none',
        '#empty_option'  => '- None -',
        '#size'          => 0,
        '#options'       => ['value1' => 'label1', 'value2' => 'label2'],
        '#default_value' => 'none'
    ];

    $form['form']['filters']['actions'] = [
        '#type'       => 'actions'
    ];

    $form['form']['filters']['actions']['submit'] = [
        '#type'  => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Filter')
    ];

    //place the table in the form
    $form['table'] = array(
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $rows,
      '#attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'bd-contact-table',
      ) 
    );

    return $form;



}

}
```

The array for the key 'filters' is the container in which all the filter will be placed. I choose the type 'fieldset', you can change the type of container to any element you want.

Afterwards I added the search and filter input and at the end the button to submit the filter-form. If you use the a class that extends the FormBase class the form will be send the the submitForm method of your class.

A thing here to notice is that every "#type" key maps to Drupal element. All elements are located in the DRUPALCORE/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element folder. Example: The #type search will map to the file Search.php within the Element folder. Every file includes a comment where all options of the element are explained.

I hope I could help you.

Nicolas

Comment: I have created the module from this [Custom Module Page](http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/my-first-drupal-8-module). May i know where to place the code in the module? or i need to know how to add a search filter in the AdminController.php, above the data listing. @traedamatic

Comment: I updated my answer and added a complete controller example code. You still can use a own Form that extends the FormBase class to accomplish the same result.

Comment: i tried your code but when i click submit, it does not submit the page. the submit button does not works. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the form wrapper around the filters. I updated the my answer.

Comment: you are awesome. code works like charm, will comment below if i get further query on this topic. thanks

Comment: may i know how to access the submitted form values, so that i can create mysql query based on the selected flelds. @traedamatic

Comment: Hey, try this in your controller: Drupal::request()->request->get(''fieldname").